Why signal values can update UI without any lag but non-signal values sometime may bring lags in ui?
We can use 2 ways of displaying a variable's value in template. Either use a signal or non-signal. I observed that using signals allow to update the UI instantly without any lag, but using non-signal values though generally updates the UI instantly but sometimes may bring tiny lags.
Why does this happen ?
